# Java EE 7, CDI 1.2, JSF 2.1, Weblogic 12.2.1 - Target Unreachable, identifier 'Controller' resolved to null

Tags: maven, jsf, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm on the verge of going crazy.
My goal was to change JSF-Managed-Beans to CDI-Managed-Beans.
I thought it was just changing Annotations. It wasn't.
I've read a lot - and more. But I just can not find my mistake.

I get this Exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: //C:/01_java/ws_bsp/bsp/bsp-web/src/main/webapp/jsf/allgemein/login.xhtml @29,86 value="#{logInOutController.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'logInOutController' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:273)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: //C:/01_java/ws_bsp/bsp/bsp-web/src/main/webapp/jsf/allgemein/login.xhtml @29,86 value="#{logInOutController.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'logInOutController' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:152)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:199)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'logInOutController' resolved to null
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:173)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:85)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:152)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

**Environment:**

- WLS 12.2.1.3.0
- Java EE 7
- ejb-project & web-project -> ear-project -> parent project

**parent project pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
<artifactId>bsp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>bsp</name>

<properties>
    <application.name>bsp</application.name>
    <application.ear.name>bsp-ear</application.ear.name>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>bsp-ear</module>
    <module>bsp-web</module>
    <module>bsp-ejb</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>wls-api</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**ear project pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>bsp</artifactId>
    <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>bsp-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>bsp-ear</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bsp-web</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/bsp</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsp-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsp-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**ejb project pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>bsp</artifactId>
    <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>bsp-ejb</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>bsp-ejb</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**web project pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>bsp</artifactId>
    <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>bsp-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>bsp-web</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsp-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<f:view contentType="text/html">

    <h:head>

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="author"
            content="ABC" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control"
            content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />

        <title><ui:insert name="title">#{app['name']}</ui:insert></title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
            href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/layout/css/custom.css" />

    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:growl id="messages" sticky="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="true"/>

        <h:panelGrid id="headerTopPanel" styleClass="zColumnTopAlign">

            <h:panelGrid id="headlinePanel" columns="3"
                columnClasses="zHeaderLinks, zHeaderMitte, zHeaderRechts">

                <logo>bsp</logo>

                <h:panelGrid id="topMenuPanel">
                    <ui:insert name="topMenu" />
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid id="iconMenuPanel">
                    <ui:insert name="iconMenu" />
                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="headerBottomPanel">

            <h:panelGrid id="breadcrumbPanel" columns="2"
                columnClasses="zLeft, zRight">

                <h:panelGrid>
                    <ui:insert name="breadcrumb" />
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:ajaxStatus styleClass="zAjaxStatus">
                        <f:facet name="start">
                            <p:commandLink styleClass="iconLoading" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="complete">
                            <h:outputText value="" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:ajaxStatus>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:separator id="menuSeparator" />

        <h:panelGrid id="middlePanel" styleClass="zColumnTopAlign">

            <!-- <h:panelGrid id="messagesPanel">
                <p:messages id="messages" showIcon="false"/>
            </h:panelGrid> -->

            <h:panelGrid id="sideMenuContentPanel" columns="2"
                columnClasses="z12percentBreit zLeft, z88percentBreit zLeft zOverflowAuto">

                <h:panelGrid id="sideMenuPanel">
                    <ui:insert name="sideMenu" />
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid id="contentPanel">
                    <ui:insert name="content" />
                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:panelGrid>

    </h:body>

</f:view>

</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
package xxx.yyy.controller;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import xxx.yyy.util.MessageHelper;
import xxx.yyy.util.PropertiesUtil;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LogInOutController {

@Inject
private PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil;

private String username;

private String password;

private String test = "test";

public String login() {
    if (username.equals("bsp") && password.equals("bsp")) {
        MessageHelper.showInfoMessage(propertiesUtil.getAppProperty("halloTest"), this);
    }
    return null;
}

public String logout() {
    return null;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(String test) {
    this.test = test;
}

}
```

If that is not enough or more is needed, please let me know.
I would be overjoyed if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You post 3 poms but do not mention in which jar/ejb/war the loginoutcontroller is. Please do. And find out if putting it directly in the war helps. Then you know way more and can post a more specific question. For the one you are asking now there are serveral duplicates. Please post the error you get in a searchengine (and maybe adding that you want to search in stackoverflow?) and read the answers, preferably the ones with high upvotes. Did they help?

Comment: The LogInOutController is in the war-project under src/main/java...
I read all answers I could find on stackoverflow and other sites. I tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: Your beans.xml is in the wrong folder. See duplicate for the correct location.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry, but no. You don't need a beans.xml at all for EE 7. It's optional.
https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/default-cdi-enablement-in-java-ee-7

Comment: @BalusC I tried it without any beans.xml. And it worked fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the reason it didn't work.
I had to change the publishing mode of the WebLogic Server:

Right Click on Server -> Properties -> WebLogic -> Publishing -> **Publish as an exploded archive**

Comment: This is not a solution since using compressed war/jar/ear files should work just as well. IF it is a solution, it is most likely e.g. doing a full new build and deploy so the class is now there which it was not in the other situation. Fix that...

Comment: @Kukeltje No, it doesn't look so. If I change it back to "Publish as a virtual application" it doesn't work. If I change it to "Publish as an exploded archive" it works.
Don't know why, but that's how it is.

Comment: But that would mean you can never create an compressed war/ear/... release build. Sure the sturcture of the war/ear if you unzip it manually is 100% identical? Check for missing files, differences and ask a new question about that!